# Having Issues setting up github actions for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am setting up GitHub actions for a Rails app. When I push to github I get an error saying Failed to initialize, db service is unhealthy

main.yml

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        ports: ['5432:5432']
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    ...
      - name: Prepare database
        run: |
           bundle exec rails db:prepare        
      - name: Run Tests
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/repairs_test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        run: |
          bundle exec rails test
```

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  database: repairs_test
```

Comment: Which step is failing? `Prepare database` or `Run Tests`?

Comment: prepare database is failing

Comment: Did you try setting up the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` env var in your service?